# Parsing specific formatted files in C

Tags: c, parsing, io

I want to parse a text file in a C program. The file contains data that is likely to be:

```
block1=
{
    a="some text with space and double quota"    
    b=random text    
    c=random text    
    d=random text    
    e=random text    
    f="number"    
    g=number    
}

block2=
    {
        a="some text with space and double quota"    
        b=random text    
        c=random text    
        d=random text    
        e=random text    
        f="number"    
        g=number    
    }
```

There may be n number of blocks, I want to create list of elements ("a" elements of each block) , for that what should I do? Is there any parsing API for text file in C?

Comment: Is this a CSV-like file (ie fields separated by a specific character like `,`)? Also, do you have access to the source code of whatever generates this file?

Comment: What do mean by you want to create a list of elements? Can you elaborate? Also, if you are simply talking about reading the above text file and saving certain pieces of information, that can be done by the `FILE` read/write :http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: text file contain separate blocks, I want to make a simple list , that contain the value of "a" from each block, Is there any way to parse file?

Comment: Well, if the blocks are consistent you could initially read `line = 3` and then progress using `line = line + 11`. Else, you could just read every line and when you encounter `line[0] = 'a'` store the information and move further.

Comment: the only "parsing API" in C is fscanf()/scanf().  It sucks.  Otherwise you need to do the work.  How about C++ ?

Comment: Will each block be complete?  Will the random text ever be enclosed in quotes?  Do you really want a list or would an array be better?  Are you sure you want an array (or list) of `a` values and a separate array (or list) of `b` values, rather than an array (or list) of blocks?  Is the number of codes fixed at `a` through `g`?  Are the names fixed at 1 character each?  Is the indentation as random as in your example?  Does the `"number"` or `number` need to be converted from a string to a number?  If so, is it a `double` or an `int` and what is the range?  What should happen on errors?

Comment: Is the order of the entries in the blocks fixed?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: continuing: will the random text include spaces/tabs/etc?

Comment: yacc. learn it. live it. love it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct block {
    char head[8];
    char braze[2];
    char a[46];
    char b[18];
    char c[18];
    char d[18];
    char e[18];
    char f[15];
    char g[13];
    char close_braze[2];
} block;

int main () {
    int i, ret;
    char a_elm[10][50];
    FILE *fp;
    block blk[10]; //use a specific number if you know. or go for linked list

    fp = fopen ("one.txt","r");

    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        ret = fread ((void *) &blk[i], sizeof (block), 1, fp);
        if (!ret)
            break;
    }
    fclose (fp);    

    for (ret = i, i = 0; i < ret; i++) {
        strncpy (a_elm[i], blk[i].a, 46);
        a_elm[i][46] = '\0';
        printf ("%s\n", a_elm[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For fixed format code, fread can be used as above or you have to use fscanf with some string functions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether there is such an API or not in C. But I think you can do it yourself with little code.

create a struct having elements as a block (having a, b, c, d, e, f, as string and g as int).
Have an array of that struct. And have a string array. Read the file using fread till end of file. After store all the "a" element of each element of the struct array in the string array.

If you want specific code, give me a sample text file you described. I'll write the code and post for you.

Comment: Thanks for reply... you can assume above two blocks as content of text file.